# Hot to show the posts that have same category id in laravel livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

the livewire component is route bonded as:

```
Route::get('/post/{post}', Bycategory::class)->name('posts.by-category');
```

in-home view I want to click on the category name and get all posts with same category:

```
 @foreach($post->categories as $category)
   <a href="{{ route('posts.by-category', $category) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
 @endforeach
```

this is bycategory livewire class:

```
public Post $post;

    public function render()
    {

Post::with('categories')->where(function ($q){
    $q->where('category_id', $this->post->categories()->id);
})->get());
        return view('livewire.post.bycategory', compact('posts'))->layout('layouts.app');
    }
```

the post and categories have many to many relations with the category_post table

but I get an error that there is not category_id in Post model;

the $this->post->categories()->id show the category id of that post;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that the the error above, it is clear that `posts table` does not have the `category_id column` and that is why you get this error. I think this is the right way to do this query

`Post::with('categories' , function ($query) { $query->where('categories.id', $this->post->categories()->id);} )->get());`

Comment: error:
mb_strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Closure given

Comment: try to replace "post::with" to "Post::whereHas"

Comment: thank you. it worked with some minor changes.

Comment: working code:

$posts = Post::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($q){
$q->where('categories.id', $this->post->categories()->first()->id);
})->get();